# How do you define a "generalized example" in algorithms?

Tags: algorithm, performance, analysis

I am attempting to understand worst case analysis and was wondering if there was some sort of way to explain the term generalized example when used in worst case running time analysis?

My first thought is that it is analyzing performance based on characteristics of inputs, but I feel like there should be a more formal way to explain it, perhaps using order notation?

Comment: Can this question be categorized as "Programming Related" ?

Comment: What's a "generalized example"? Please define it. @Atf Questions about algorithms / complexity are fine on SO. **Even though** they are much better off at other SE sites like cs.stackexchange.com  , and by my experience questions are answered in a much better way there than on SO.

Comment: @Bakuriu: Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Generalized example can be considered as the version of a particular instance of a problem where all independent variables are parameterized. (i.e. using symbols and variables instead of values) I'd say the range of those parameters/variables would also be defined, as well. Also, in a generalized example, certain non-numeric *generalizations* would have been performed. One example that pops into mind is, instead of considering a specific graph, saying that the problem is defined over simple directed graphs.